# Cast BigDecimal in Postgre numeric value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "words")
public class Words implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "keyword", length = 200, unique = true)
    private String keyword;

    @Column(name = "low_range", length = 100)
    private BigDecimal lowRange;

    @Column(name = "high_range", length = 100)
    private BigDecimal highRange;
}
```

I use this query to make SQL updates:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="update processed_words set low_range = :lowRange, high_range = :highRange where keyword = :keyword", nativeQuery = true)
int updateByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword,
                    @Param("lowRange") BigDecimal lowRange,
                    @Param("highRange") BigDecimal highRange);
```

PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    high_range double precision,
    low_range double precision
)
```

When I perform the update query I get this exception:

```
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "low_range" is of type double precision but expression is of type bytea
      Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Do you know how I can cast low_range value into the native SQL query?
```

PS. Postgres log file:

```
2022-11-13 16:47:38.721 UTC [3254525] admin@engine LOG:  execute S_2: BEGIN
2022-11-13 16:47:38.721 UTC [3254525] admin@engine ERROR:  column "low_range" is of type double precision but expression is of type bytea at character 59
2022-11-13 16:47:38.721 UTC [3254525] admin@engine HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
2022-11-13 16:47:38.721 UTC [3254525] admin@engine STATEMENT:  update words set low_range = $1, high_range = $2 where keyword = $3
2022-11-13 16:47:38.763 UTC [3254525] admin@engine LOG:  execute S_6: ROLLBACK
2022-11-13 16:47:38.871 UTC [3254525] admin@engine LOG:  execute S_2: BEGIN
```

Comment: The error message is different, it says you're using binary data: "but expression is of type bytea". Could you share your SQL statement? (check the log files)

Comment: I added log file into the post. Can you advise how I can fix this?